# How to break up two xml tags with the same subchild names in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, for-xml

I have created a script which takes data from a table in SQL and generates an XML output. The parent, child and sub-child tags are all the same which for 2 tags. The SQL script is outputting them as one XML value instead of 2.

```
 SELECT
 Request.TransactionRef AS [RequestHeader/RequestID],
'Deal.Trial' AS [RequestHeader/Action],
'DoDealValidate' AS [RequestHeader/ActionFlags/Flag],
'DoDealDerive' AS [RequestHeader/ActionFlags/Flag]
```

The current results are:

```
<ActionFlags>
<Flag>DoDealValidateDoDealDerive</Flag>
</ActionFlags>




<ActionFlags>
<Flag>DoDealValidate</Flag>
<Flag>DoDealDerive</Flag>
</ActionFlags>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place something **empty** in between:

```
SELECT
 'blah' AS [RequestHeader/RequestID],
'Deal.Trial' AS [RequestHeader/Action],
'DoDealValidate' AS [RequestHeader/ActionFlags/Flag],
NULL AS [RequestHeader/ActionFlags],
'DoDealDerive' AS [RequestHeader/ActionFlags/Flag] 
FOR XML PATH('row');
```

The background:

The engine is running through the SELECT's columns and builds them one after the other.

- Well, there is a `<RequestHeader>` to open
- and there is a `<RequestID>` to open
- Again the `<RequestHeader>`, still open, nothin to to
- and there is `<Action>` below... Oh, we must close the `<RequestID>` and open a new `<Action>`
- and so on...

In your code the `<Flag>` is still open, therefore the content is written into the open element.

My change will let the engine think

- Ah, we move up one level, so we close the `<Flag>` first... Oops, there's nothing to write...
- Now there is something for `<Flag>`, which is not open anymore, we have to re-open a (new) `<Flag>` node
- and so on...